# unfreeze SSD disk when kernel does not support "suspend"

Tags: kernel, power-management, ssd, hdparm

I need to secure erase SSD disk with `hdparm` on my server:

```
hdparm --user-master u --security-erase NULL /dev/sda
```

but the disk is currently "frozen", as reported by `hdparm`:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep frozen
```

All instructions suggest I should put my server to sleep to unfreeze. But my kernel does not have suspend compiled in.

How can I unfreeze the SSD ?

Comment: Rebooting the machine is an option?

Comment: @Paulo Tomé - rebooting is not a problem. Why do you ask?

Comment: Have you tried. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Paulo Tomé - I don't understand what solution you are suggesting. The server is running now, at some point in the past it was shut off. When I simply restart it, I will end up in same situation where I am now.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to a kernel that supports suspend? The following link may be of some help: https://askubuntu.com/a/113608/170550

Comment: [ATA Secure Erase - ata Wiki](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase#Step_1a_-_Ensure_the_drive_is_not_frozen:). It's good you have the drive currently frozen. This Wiki warns that not using a password for security erase might almost brick the drive (on Lenovo): [Executing security erase without setting a password - WARNING: DO NOT DO THIS!](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase#Executing_security_erase_without_setting_a_password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could well be that your BIOS freezes the disk when booting, that's why suspend/resume helps because it power cycles the drive without the BIOS getting its hands on it again (see [this convo/comment](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982585&p=12485246#post12485246) over at the Ubuntu Forums).

An alternative to suspending/resuming would be (if your hardware and BIOS allow it) to configure the port the disk is attached to AHCI, i.e. make it hot-pluggable and then unplug and after a while replug the drive (when nothing on that disk is in use, of course).